# Is there a way to test a set of inputs versus a set of outputs in a single @Test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Is there a way to take a set of similar tests like

```
  @Test
  public void testA()  {
    when(foo.getVal()).thenReturn("A");
    response = myService.doThings(foo);
    assert(response.getCode() == 200);
  }

  @Test
  public void testB()  {
    when(foo.getVal()).thenReturn("B");
    response = myService.doThings(foo);
    assert(response.getCode() == 404);
  }

  @Test
  public void testC()  {
    when(foo.getVal()).thenReturn("C");
    response = myService.doThings(foo);
    assert(response.getCode() == 200);
  }
```

and do something like (made-up syntax):

```
  @Test
  public void testABC()  {
    when(foo.getVal()).thenReturnEach("A", "B", "C");
    response = myService.doThings(foo);
    assertEach(/* somehow check a list of 200, 404, 200 */);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a parameterized test.  
The idea is to define a "generic" method where you define a set of input and a set of expected.

But Mockito will not help here as it is not the job of mocking libraries to run/execute tests.
Your favorite unit test library (mine is JUnit) will very well address it.

For example with [JUnit 4 parameterized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/parameterized-tests) (old way), you could write something as :

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {     
                 { "A", 200 }, { "B", 404 }, { "C", 200 } 
                 });
    }

    private int valInput;

    private String responseCodeOutput;

    private Foo foo = ...;

    public MyServiceTest(String valInput, int responseCodeOutput) {
        this.valInput = valInput;
        this.responseCodeOutput = responseCodeOutput;
    }

    @Test
    public void doThings() {     
        when(foo.getVal()).thenReturnEach(valInput);
        String response = myService.doThings(foo);
        Assert.assertEqual(responseCodeOutput, response);
    }
}
```

With JUnit 5 that was recently released, it would be still cleaner and simpler :

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("doThingsProvider")
void doThings (String valInput, int expectedCode) {         
      when(foo.getVal()).thenReturnEach(valInput);
      String response = myService.doThings(foo);
      Assert.assertEqual(expectedCode, response);      
}

static Stream<Arguments> doThingsProvider() {
    return Stream.of(
        Arguments.of("A", 200),
        Arguments.of("B", 404),
        Arguments.of("C", 200),
    );
}
```

Comment: Parameterized tests are needed, but in the OP example, a mock library like Mockito is also needed because what is being parameterized is the behavior of a collaborator, not inputs to the SUT.

Comment: @Kevin Welker I agree totally. I referred to test execution. I updated to be a little more specific.

Comment: in both of your examples, I think you have the parameter types reversed

Comment: @Kevin Welker You are right. Writing code without IDE is sometimes a little error-prone. I corrected. Thanks to you :)